# How to hide block with keyframes?

Tags: html, css

Now after the animation is an empty div .text. I have to hide the block completely with smooth opacity animation. (such as display:none, but display: none doesn't animate) How do it with keyframes?

```css
.text {
  animation:  opacity-animation .5s forwards;
}

@keyframes opacity-animation {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">text text text text</div>
This fist stroke of text
```

Comment: You cannot animate the `display` property.

Comment: You probably gonna need js to do it exactly the way you want. display property just doesn't work with animations.

Answer (score 0):

`animation` does not work with `display`.
But you can try something like this:

```css
.text {
    animation: opacity-animation .5s forwards;
}

@keyframes opacity-animation {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">text text text text</div>
This fist stroke of text
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute;` in animation.

```css
.text {
  animation:  opacity-animation 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes opacity-animation {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">text text text text</div>
This fist stroke of text
```